# Guzzle returns cURL error 3: <url> malformed

Tags: php, laravel, curl, guzzle

I want to try out the guzzle library and am following through their [quickstart](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) tutorial to make http requests to an api.

Yet it doesn't seem to work, because I get the following error:

```
cURL error 3: <url> malformed
```

Since I have never worked with cURL before, I don't even know how to respond to that error message. Here is my code with the request I am making:

```
    $client = new Client();
    $client->get('/', ['verify' => true]);

    $response = $client->get('https://api.github.com/');

    dd($response);
```

I am using the Laravel 5 framework and calling the index method in my HomeController. Also am using WAMP.

I would appreciate any help and suggestion, because I would like to try Guzzle out.

Here is a picture of the Error Message I get:

[image: Laravel 5 Error Message]

Comment: if my answer below was helpful, you can accept it :)

Comment: @loveAndHappiness did you get any solution to solve this issue ? i have same same issue in my code :( please help me

Comment: I hadn't had the time to implement any solution to this project yet, so I don't know if the provided solution solved the issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to disable verification (**don't do this!**):

```
$response = $client->get('https://api.github.com/', ['verify' => false]);
```

Rather than disabling verification entirely, this can likely be fixed by providing proper CA bundle file. See [`verify`](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/clients.html#verify) in Guzzle documentation.

```
$client->setDefaultOption(
    'verify', 
    'C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt'
);
```

Comment: Actually that is not the issue, because without this line, I get another error "cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate", and the guzzle faq says that this line needs to be there.

Comment: Not sure how this solves a "malformed URL" error, or why it was marked accepted.

Answer (score 26):

In case you came here because you googled "Guzzle returns cURL error 3:  malformed" check the client parameter. In some version it's **base_uri** and other **base_url**

```
    $client = new Client([
        'base_uri' => 'http://localhost:8000',  // <-- base_uri instead of base_url
    ]);
```

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you. I got the base_uri value from APP_URL in .env file.

Comment: Same thing here, I had the URL with `/` in the end. Left it without `/` then added the `/` in the beginning of my call and it worked.

Comment: I know very old post, but thanks, you saved my day

Answer (score 11):

You should not have this call:

```
$client->get('/', ['verify' => true]);
```

That is what is throwing the error. The third line is okay.

The error is means what it says. The URL `/` is obviously not valid. When you instantiate the client, use the `base_uri` option, or specify a full URL in the call to `get()`.

Comment: What is the problem with line 2 and why should OP not have it?

Comment: In line one when initializing the guzzle client he had not passed in a url.
So in line two, when he uses '/', there is no base url and an error is bound to be thrown [malformed url]

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I mistakenly named my environment file as "env"

Make sure it exists at root path and named ".env"