# cURL error 60: SSL certificate: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: php, ssl, curl, stripe-payments

I am trying to send an API request using Stripe but get the error message:

> cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

This is the code I am running:

```
public function chargeStripe()
{
    $stripe = new Stripe;
    $stripe = Stripe::make(env('STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY'));

    $charge = $stripe->charges()->create([
        'amount'   => 2900,
        'customer' => Input::get('stripeEmail'),
        'currency' => 'EUR',
    ]);

    return Redirect::route('step1');
}
```

I searched a lot on Google and lots of people are suggesting that I download this file: [cacert.pem](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem), put it somewhere and reference it in my php.ini. This is the part in my php.ini:

```
curl.cainfo = "C:\Windows\cacert.pem"
```

Yet, even after restarting my server several times and changing the path, I get the same error message.

I have the ssl_module enabled in Apache, and I have php_curl enabled in my `php.ini`.

I have also tried another fix which suggests that I add these lines to my cURL options:

```
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
```

Where do I add options to my cURL? Apparently not through the command line, since my CLI doesn't find the command "curl_setopt"

Comment: Assuming there are no issues with your code, it could be your firewall. Try disabling your firewall to test.

Comment: did't I gave you answer to this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29722864/1331425)? :)

Comment: @limonte possible, had to switch projects and have probably the same problem with the new project. Will switch back to the guzzle problem and maybe it is the same fix. brb

Comment: @Waqarulislam firewall always down

Comment: I don't get it, do you have cURL in a PHP script, as in `curl_init()` etc, or are you running curl from the command line. It doesn't really help to change the PHP settings if you're not using PHP cURL, and those two lines at the bottom of the question are settings for PHP cURL.

Comment: Have you tried the latest version of stripe? I see a commit message that changed something to do with certs... https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/commit/f7ee3edb828548ff6799d1fa0fe8f65e0bc54c01

Comment: @LoveAndHappiness have you got the solution for this problem? I am facing the same error with stripe. Please let me know if you have any solution.

Comment: @thelastshadow That's a different stripe library than the one OP is using :)

Comment: This solved the issue for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32095378/178163

Comment: Attn: WordPress users. WP curl functions use a CA cert file in the WP core files - not your php.ini defined file. So even after you make the fixes shown here, you will still get the error. I made a little plugin to solve this: https://github.com/squarecandy/force-localhost-ca

Comment: The link to how fix PHP curl leads to a maliscious spam site.

Comment: Check my Solution that is easy to use and correct.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858351/php-ssl-certificate-error-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate/61177063#61177063

Answer (score 749, accepted):

How to solve this problem:

- download and extract [cacert.pem](https://curl.se/ca/cacert.pem) following the instructions at https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html
- save it on your filesystem somewhere (for example, XAMPP users might use `C:\xampp\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem`)
- in your php.ini, put this file location in the `[curl]` section (putting it in the `[openssl]` section is also a good idea):

```
[curl]
curl.cainfo = "C:\xampp\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"

[openssl]
openssl.cafile = "C:\xampp\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"
```

- restart your webserver (e.g. Apache) and PHP FPM server if applicable

(Reference: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)

Comment: This message is coming because of your PHP version. If it is upper from PHP 5.5 then coming this error because of PHP 5.6 new feature. PHP 5.6 check certificates if you are using cURL.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Although I would recommend using the cacert.pem from the official curl-page: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

Comment: Just wanted to point out for anyone that can't get this to work - I used forward slashes `curl.cainfo = "C:/cacert.pem"` and also had to restart my computer in order to get it to work. Just restarting the web server was not enough. Hopefully that helps :]

Comment: and don't forget to uncomment `curl.cainfo` (facepalm)

Comment: Thanks!  I'm not running XAMPP, but am on Windows.  This solution worked for me, just parked it here instead: `"C:\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"`.

Comment: What about MAMP?

Comment: I followed this, but I am still getting the same issue. Is there anything else I need to do?
XAMPP, windows 10, PHP 7.2.8, http://localhost:8080/

Comment: Resolved issue by following the : https://www.scratchcode.io/curl-error-ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate/

Hope this helps anyone who is reading this comment

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me when I was setting up a new laptop and getting an error "No alive nodes found in your cluster" when trying to connect to AWS Elasticsearch.

Comment: this is also working for ampps, you can just locate the php.ini and add the same variable and location of the cacert file thanks!!

Comment: I got the exact same error, still line 60, using php artisan with OctoberCMS. I discovered a recent version of cacert.pem inside of: `composer/ca-bundle/res/cacert.pem` of my project directory. So I opened php.ini, the one used my command line (not the one used by apache), and set `curl.cainfo` directive to point to it. With Wamp, use absolute paths like: "c:/path/to/file"

Answer (score 148):

Attention Wamp/Wordpress/windows users. I had this issue for hours and not even the correct answer was doing it for me, because i was editing the wrong php.ini file because the question was answered to XAMPP and not for WAMP users, even though the question was for WAMP.

Here's what I did:

1. Download the [certificate bundle.](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html)
2. Put it inside of `C:\wamp64\bin\php\your php version\extras\ssl`
3. Inside of `C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache(version)\modules`, make sure the file `mod_ssl.so` is there
4. Inside of Apache directory `C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.27\conf`, enable `mod_ssl` in `httpd.conf`
5. Enable `php_openssl.dll` in `php.ini`. Be aware my problem was that I had two php.ini files and I need to do this in both of them. First one can be located inside of your WAMP taskbar icon here.

   [image]

   And the other one is located in `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php(Version)`

   Find the location for both of the `php.ini` files and find the line `curl.cainfo =` and give it a path like this `curl.cainfo = "C:\wamp64\bin\php\php(Version)\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"`
6. Now save the files and restart your server and you should be good to go

Comment: It's less that you have to do both php.ini than doing the one you are intending to use: if you're using apache as the SAPI client, then amend the one in the apache dir, and/or amend the one in the client dir if you're planning to use php.exe as the SAPI.

Comment: "I need to do this in both of them" is the key note. Thank you

Comment: This works for Laravel 5.5 with "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3". Wamp server 3.1.3. Php 7.1*

Comment: Thanks for answering for wamp

Comment: You are awesome! This is the only solution that worked for me after looking to resolve the problem for hours. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! The first solution I have found for this problem that is not "If you are using XAMPP do this."

Comment: Rerun `php artisan serv` if you use Laravel

Comment: Well done, I tried to fix the issues for hours and I try to read carefully the path of `php.ini`, and I was editing that file from the apache folder, not in the PHP folder 

Comment: Is there a setting for open-source developers to enable or signify this from composer?

Answer (score 61):

If you are using PHP 5.6 with Guzzle, Guzzle has switched to using the PHP libraries autodetect for certificates rather than it's process ([ref](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/request-options.html#verify-option)).  PHP outlines the changes [here](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.openssl.php).

## Finding out Where PHP/Guzzle is Looking for Certificates

You can dump where PHP is looking using the following PHP command:

```
 var_dump(openssl_get_cert_locations());
```

## Getting a Certificate Bundle

For OS X testing, you can use homebrew to install openssl `brew install openssl` and then use `openssl.cafile=/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem` in your php.ini or Zend Server settings (under OpenSSL).

A certificate bundle is also available from curl/Mozilla on the curl website: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

## Telling PHP Where the Certificates Are

Once you have a bundle, either place it where PHP is already looking (which you found out above) or update `openssl.cafile` in php.ini.  (Generally, `/etc/php.ini` or `/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini` or `/etc/php/php.ini` on Unix.)

Comment: YES. After seeing too many people suggest the obviously wrong approach of downgrading by multiple version numbers, this stands as the correct approach imho. I had followed others' advice about the cafile but didn't have a means of testing why it still didn't load. This openssl_get_cert_locations() function really did the job in identifying my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for providing `openssl_get_cert_locations`, it made debugging much easier. Looks like WAMP uses different ini file for apache php than for console php. In my case, I had to add `openssl.cafile="c:/_/cacert.pem"` for console-based php. Last time, when using it through apache, I needed `curl.cainfo="c:/_/cacert.pem"` to make it work.

Comment: Anyone have a suggestion for windows machines? I tried the suggested command in Git Bash, cmd, and Commander. None of them recognized the syntax for `var_dump(openssl_get_cert_locations());`

Comment: `var_dump(openssl_get_cert_locations());` is a PHP command, you'll need to run it in a PHP file or interpreter.  (Updated the post for clarity that it is a PHP command.)

Comment: You can run  `echo "<?php var_dump(openssl_get_cert_locations());" | php` in your console project and you'll be ready to go

Answer (score 21):

Guzzle, which is used by [cartalyst/stripe](https://github.com/cartalyst/stripe), will do the following to find a proper certificate archive to check a server certificate against:

1. Check if `openssl.cafile` is set in your php.ini file.
2. Check if `curl.cainfo` is set in your php.ini file.
3. Check if `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt` exists (Red Hat, CentOS, Fedora; provided by the ca-certificates package)
4. Check if `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` exists (Ubuntu, Debian; provided by the ca-certificates package)
5. Check if `/usr/local/share/certs/ca-root-nss.crt` exists (FreeBSD; provided by the ca_root_nss package)
6. Check if `/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem` (OS X; provided by homebrew)
7. Check if `C:\windows\system32\curl-ca-bundle.crt` exists (Windows)
8. Check if `C:\windows\curl-ca-bundle.crt` exists (Windows)

You will want to make sure that the values for the first two settings are properly defined by doing a simple test:

```
echo "openssl.cafile: ", ini_get('openssl.cafile'), "\n";
echo "curl.cainfo: ", ini_get('curl.cainfo'), "\n";
```

Alternatively, try to write the file into the locations indicated by #7 or #8.

Answer (score 19):

If you're unable to change php.ini you could also point to the cacert.pem file from code like this:

```
$http = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['verify' => '/path/to/cacert.pem']);
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setHttpClient($http);
```

Answer (score 12):

I had this problem appear out-of-the-blue one day, when a Guzzle(5) script was attempting to connect to a host over SSL. Sure, I could disable the VERIFY option in Guzzle/Curl, but that's clearly not the correct way to go.

I tried *everything* listed here and in similar threads, then eventually went to terminal with openssl to test against the domain with which I was trying to connect:

```
openssl s_client -connect example.com:443
```

... and received first few lines indicating:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 CN = example.com
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = example.com
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
```

... while everything worked fine when trying other destinations (ie: google.com, etc)

This prompted me to contact the domain I had been trying to connect to, and indeed, they had a problem on THEIR END that had crept up.  It was resolved and my script went back to working.

So... if you're pulling your hair out, give openssl a shot and see if there's anything up with the response from the location you are attempting to connect. Maybe the issue isn't so 'local' after all sometimes.

Comment: Excellent advice here...confirm the _actual_ problem before you go ripping into config...

Answer (score 12):

What i did was use `var_dump(openssl_get_cert_locations()); die;` in any php script, which gave me the information about defaults that my local php was using:

```
array (size=8)
  'default_cert_file' => string 'c:/openssl-1.0.1c/ssl/cert.pem' (length=30)
  'default_cert_file_env' => string 'SSL_CERT_FILE' (length=13)
  'default_cert_dir' => string 'c:/openssl-1.0.1c/ssl/certs' (length=27)
  'default_cert_dir_env' => string 'SSL_CERT_DIR' (length=12)
  'default_private_dir' => string 'c:/openssl-1.0.1c/ssl/private' (length=29)
  'default_default_cert_area' => string 'c:/openssl-1.0.1c/ssl' (length=21)
  'ini_cafile' => string 'E:\xampp\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem' (length=34)
  'ini_capath' => string '' (length=0)
```

As you can notice, i have set the ini_cafile or the ini option curl.cainfo. But in my case, curl would try to use the "default_cert_file" which did not exist.

I copied the file from https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem into the location for "default_cert_file" (c:/openssl-1.0.1c/ssl/cert.pem) and i was able to get it to work.

This was the only solution for me.

Comment: I have similar problem and my location is something like

          c:/usr/local/ssl/cert.pem
but this location does not exists, do you what what it could be, further the same project is used by my coluge on mac machine could that be reason, I have tried everything else, that is adding cert location in .ini file but it doesn't work, it looks like your solution should work as it makes sense but can't change that location and can't put certificate in location which doesn't exists.

Comment: You can try an create the folders and put certificate at your specified path?

Answer (score 10):

Have you tried..

```
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

If you would like to risk being hit by a man-in-the-middle attack, you can skip the verify.

Answer (score 7):

Be sure that you open the `php.ini` file directly by your Window Explorer. (in my case: `C:\DevPrograms\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25`).

Don't use the shortcut to `php.ini` in the Wamp/Xamp icon's menu in the System Tray. This shortcut doesn't work in this case.

Then edit that `php.ini` :

```
curl.cainfo ="C:/DevPrograms/wamp64/bin/php/cacert.pem"
```

and

```
openssl.cafile="C:/DevPrograms/wamp64/bin/php/cacert.pem"
```

After saving `php.ini` you don't need to "Restart All Services" in Wamp icon or close/re-open CMD.

Comment: Looks like the WAMP `php.ini` shortcut in thy system tray is a `.symlink` (0 bytes). It opens(or creates?) the file: `<path_to_WAMP_install_location>\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.41\bin\php.ini` (in my case 74bytes). This answer suggests going directly to the WAMP folder for the PHP version you are using, and editing that `php.ini` (in my case 73bytes) file instead.

Comment: The comment the top of the `wamp\64\bin\php\php.x.y.z` directory says: `[PHP]
; **************************************************************
; ****** DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE **** DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE ******
; * This file is only use by PHP CLI (Command Line Interface)  *
; * that is to say by Wampserver internal PHP scripts          *
; * THE CORRECT FILE TO EDIT is Wampmanager Icon->PHP->php.ini *
; * that is wamp/bin/apache/apache2.x.y/bin/php.ini            *
; **************************************************************
`` This is for PHP 7.3.12

Comment: Actually, it seems that the symlink points to `<path_to_WAMP_install_directory>\wamp64\bin\php\php7.3.12\phpForApache.ini`, which is in the same directory as the php.ini file that has a comment that it should not be edited. There are also developer and production versions of php.ini in the same location.

Answer (score 6):

For WAMP, this is what finally worked for me.
While it is similar to others, the solutions mentioned on this page, and other locations on the web did not work. Some "minor" detail differed.
Either the location to save the PEM file mattered, but was not specified clearly enough.
Or WHICH `php.ini` file to be edited was incorrect. Or both.
I'm running a 2020 installation of WAMP 3.2.0 on a Windows 10 machine.

#### Link to get the pem file:

http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
Copy the entire page and save it as: `cacert.pem`, in the location mentioned below.

#### Save the PEM file in this location

`<wamp install directory>\bin\php\php<version>\extras\ssl`
eg saved file and path: "T:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.3.12\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"

**(I had originally saved it elsewhere (and indicated the saved location in the php.ini file, but that did not work).
There might, or might not be, other locations also work. This was the recommended location - I do not know why.)*

WHERE
`<wamp install directory>` = path to your WAMP installation.
eg:  `T:\wamp64\`

`<php version>` of php that WAMP is running: (to find out, goto: `WAMP icon tray ->  PHP   <version number>`
if the version number shown is 7.3.12, then the directory would be: php7.3.12)
eg: `php7.3.12`

#### Which php.ini file to edit

To open the proper `php.ini` file for editing, goto: `WAMP icon tray ->  PHP -> php.ini`.
eg: `T:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.41\bin\php.ini`
NOTE: it is NOT the file in the php directory!

**Update:**
While it *looked* like I was editing the file:   `T:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.41\bin\php.ini`,
it was actually editing that file's symlink target:  `T:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.3.12/phpForApache.ini`.

Note that if you follow the above directions, you are NOT editing a `php.ini` file directly.  You are actually editing a `phpForApache.ini` file.  (a post with info about [symlinks](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-take-advantage-of-symbolic-links-in-window-10/))

If you read the comments at the top of *some* of the `php.ini` files in various WAMP directories, it specifically states to NOT EDIT that particular file.
Make sure that the file you do open for editing does not include this warning.

Installing the extension  [Link Shell Extension](https://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html) allowed me to see the target of the symlink in the file Properites window, via an added tab.  here is an [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10188485/windows-symbolic-link-target/64229813#64229813) of mine with more info about this extension.

If you run various versions of php at various times, you may need to save the PEM file in each relevant php directory.

#### The edits to make in your php.ini file:

Paste the path to your PEM file in the following locations.

- uncomment `;curl.cainfo =` and paste in the path to your PEM file.
  eg: `curl.cainfo = "T:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.3.12\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"`
- uncomment `;openssl.cafile=` and paste in the path to your PEM file.
  eg: `openssl.cafile="T:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.3.12\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"`

**Credits:**

*While not an official resource, here is a link back to the YouTube video that got the last of the details straightened out for me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fn1V4yQNgLs*.

Comment: This comment right here will save you lots of time if you are using Wampp with different PHP versions:

While it looked like I was editing the file: T:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.41\bin\php.ini,
it was actually editing that file's symlink target: T:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.3.12/phpForApache.ini.

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution that worked for me. I downgraded from the latest guzzle to version ~4.0 and it worked.

In composer.json add "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~4.0"

Hope it helps someone

Comment: That will also prevent you using any version 5/6 features. Instead just set verify to false in a param array (3rd param of request method): $client->request('GET', '/', ['verify' => false]);

Answer (score 3):

I just experienced this same problem with the Laravel 4 php framework which uses the `guzzlehttp/guzzle` composer package. For some reason, the SSL certificate for mailgun stopped validating suddenly and I got that same "error 60" message.

If, like me, you are on a shared hosting without access to `php.ini`, the other solutions are not possible. In any case, Guzzle has this client initializing code that would most likely nullify the `php.ini` effects:

```
// vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php
    $settings = [
        'allow_redirects' => true,
        'exceptions'      => true,
        'decode_content'  => true,
        'verify'          => __DIR__ . '/cacert.pem'
    ];
```

Here Guzzle forces usage of its own internal cacert.pem file, which is probably now out of date, instead of using the one provided by [cURL's environment](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html). Changing this line (on Linux at least) configures Guzzle to use cURL's default SSL verification logic and fixed my problem:

Since the files in `vendor` are not meant to be tampered with, a better solution would be to [configure the Guzzle client](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#verify-option) on usage, but this was just too difficult to do in Laravel 4.

Hope this saves someone else a couple hours of debugging...

Comment: This helped thanks, instead of changing it in vendor, you can overwrite the settings when you init the Guzzle Client:

$client = new Client(['defaults' => ['verify' => true]]);

Answer (score 3):

All of the answers are correct ; **but the most important thing** is You have to find the right php.ini file. 
check this command in cmd **" php --ini "  is not the right answer** for finding the right php.ini file.

if you edit

```
curl.cainfo ="PATH/cacert.pem"
```

and check

```
var_dump(openssl_get_cert_locations());
```

then curl.cainfo should have a value. **if not then that's not right php.ini file;**

***I recommend you to search *.ini  in wamp/bin or xxamp/bin or any server you use and change them one by one and check it. ***

Comment: Worked for me on windows server path `iis_express/php`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This might be an edge case, but in my case the problem was not the *client conf* (I already had *`curl.cainfo`* configured in *`php.ini`*), but rather the remote server not being configured properly:

It did not send any intermediate *certs* in the chain. There was no error browsing the site using Chrome, but with PHP I got following error.

> cURL error 60

After including the *Intermediate Certs* in the remote webserver configuration it worked.

You can use this site to check the SSL configuration of your server:

https://whatsmychaincert.com/

Answer (score 2):

I spent too much time to figure out this problem for me.

I had PHP version 5.5 and I needed to upgrade to 5.6.

In versions < 5.6 Guzzle will use it's own cacert.pem file, but in higher versions of PHP it will use system's cacert.pem file.

I also downloaded file from here https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html and set it in php.ini.

Answer found in Guzzles StreamHandler.php file https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/0773d442aa96baf19d7195f14ba6e9c2da11f8ed/src/Handler/StreamHandler.php#L437

> ```
>         // PHP 5.6 or greater will find the system cert by default. When
>         // < 5.6, use the Guzzle bundled cacert.
> ```

Answer (score 2):

For those of you who are trying to use Wordpress's application password functionality on your local machine. You need to update the `wp-includes\certificates\ca-bundle.crt`

### Open this file in a text editor and append your server's certificate.

1. Open your self-signed certificate(.crt) file and
2. Copy all between and including

**----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----**

**-----END CERTIFICATE-----**

3. Paste at the end of the `wp-includes\certificates\ca-bundle.crt`

Answer (score 2):

Easy way for user using Wordpress to fix cURL error 60

Appearance > Theme Editor > functions.php or
or edit your functions.php file

`add_filter('https_ssl_verify', '__return_false');`

and it works

Comment: Disabling SSL verification seems like a really really bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

when I run `'var_dump(php_ini_loaded_file());'`
I get this output on my page
`'C:\Development\bin\apache\apache2.4.33\bin\php.ini' (length=50)'`

and to get php to load my cert file I had to edit the php.ini in this path `'C:\Development\bin\apache\apache2.4.33\bin\php.ini'`
and add `openssl.cafile="C:/Development/bin/php/php7.2.4/extras/ssl/cacert.pem"` where I had downloaded and place my cert file from https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

am on windows 10, using drupal 8, wamp and php7.2.4

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Centos 7 with the free version of virtualmin.  With Virtualmin you can create a wordpress website.  There is functionality that will automatically update your ssl certificate for you.  I noticed that **/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf** did not contain an entry for **SSLCertificateChainFile**.  Which should be set to something like /home/websitename/ssl.combined.  Updating that file accordingly and restarting apache fix this problem for me.  I discovered my issue trying to install a jetpack plugin for wordpress.  A search on the internet led me to realize that [I didn't have SSL Configured](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/jetpack-cannot-connect-curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-problem/).  I followed [Redhat's instructions](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/43575) on how to install a certificate.  I hope this was useful to someone.

Comment: Thanks Sean, this was the exact issue i was facing, will try it

Answer (score 0):

if you use WAMP you should also add the certificate line in php.ini for Apache (besides the default php.ini file):

```
[curl]
curl.cainfo = C:\your_location\cacert.pem
```

works for php5.3+

Comment: Yes! Be careful to edit both apache and php version php.ini files. For WAMP users, this answer was the only to solve my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858351/php-ssl-certificate-error-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate/32095378#

Answer (score 0):

I have a proper solution of this problem, lets try and understand the root cause of this issue. This issue comes when remote servers ssl cannot be verified using root certificates in your system's certificate store or remote ssl is not installed along with chain certificates. If you have a linux system with root ssh access, then in this case you can try updating your certificate store with below command:

**`update-ca-certificates`**

If still, it doesn't work then you need to add root and interim certificate of remote server in your cert store. You can download root and intermediate certs and add them in ***/usr/local/share/ca-certificates*** directory and then run command **`update-ca-certificates`**. This should do the trick. Similarly for windows you can search how to add root and intermediate cert.

The other way you can solve this problem is by asking remote server team to add ssl certificate as a bundle of domain root cert, intermediate cert and root cert.

Answer (score 0):

**Guzzle Version 5**

This default config is working good for mine. It will disable https required.

```
  $options = [
    'defaults' => ['verify' => false],
  ];
  new GuzzleClient($options);
```

In other case, you want to set path of ca, change to:

```
['verify' => '/path/to/cacert.pem']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using plain cUrl then you have set **CURLOPT_CAINFO** option for the request. this path should be the absolute path.

You can download this certificate from [here](https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) then place it in following path:

> C:\wamp64\bin\php\php(your PHP version)\extras\ssl\

```
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'C:\wamp64\bin\php\php(your PHP version)\extras\ssl\cacert.pem');
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add this value in three places on Windows server:

```
[curl]
curl.cainfo = "C:\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"

[openssl]
openssl.cafile = "C:\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"
openssl.capath = "C:\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"
```

Answer (score -1):

As you are using Windows, I think your path separator is '\' (and '/' on Linux). 
Try using the constant `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`. Your code will be more portable.

Try:

```
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'cacert.pem');
```

EDIT: and write the full path. I had some issues with relative paths (perhaps curl is executed from another base directory?)

Comment: This wouldn't make a difference, because the actual cURL settings are out of your control when you use that particular Stripe library.