# cURL error 60: SSL certificate prblm: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: php, youtube-api, wamp, youtube-data-api

I want to collect a list of videos uploaded on a specific channel using the YouTube data API. However, before implementing online I am trying to get my code running on an offline environment (WAMPserver, PHP 5.5.12, Apache 2.4.9). I am using the following code:

```
require_once 'google-api-php-client-2.0.0-RC5/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("SRC_Thor");
$client->setDeveloperKey("xxxxxxxxxxx");

$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

$channelResponse = $youtube->channels->listChannels('contentDetails', []);
var_dump($channelResponse);
```

However it gives the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException' with message 'cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see `http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html`)'

I have tried adding the latest version of `cacert.pem` as most topics on SO offer as a solution, however to no avail.

Comment: Since you're in a development environment, why don't you just set `$client->setDefaultOption('verify', false);` so that it doesn't attempt to perform the verification? Obviously on the live server it won't be an issue given that the live server will have a correct certificate (assumedly)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy of course, I was put off by all the security thread comments everywhere, but that's a non-issue. Thanks!

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I am getting an error: `Call to undefined method Google_Client::setDefaultOption()` any idea why?

Comment: I guess `setDefaultOption` method has been removed from `Google_Client`. Use [@Phung answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40487704/5560399) it worked for me!

Comment: I find that the closure here is not optimal. Almost none of the answers over there cover the ground where we want to use the google client in testing, from a local dev, where going through setting a certificate is quite inappropriate, whereas answers here mostly address it. I wonder if this one could be phrased differently to insist on the local testing part even more.

Comment: @Félix Adriyel Gagnon-Grenier if you have any suggestions on how to do that, feel free to help out. It's been very long since I worked on that project and I could really use your help in helping others.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

If you are on Windows using Xampp, I am stealing a better answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34883260), would be helpful if Google shows you this question first.

1. Download and extract for cacert.pem here (a clean file format/data)

   > https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html
2. Put it in :

   > C:\xampp\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem
3. Add this line to your php.ini

   > curl.cainfo = "C:\xampp\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"
4. restart your webserver/Apache

Comment: And if you are using Wamp, you need to modify phpForApache.ini

Comment: I use wamp server. `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.4.4\phpForApache.ini` . Restarting PC worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: 6 years and your solution just saved me today! Thanks!
The same solution would work if you're running a custom WAMP configuration, not just xampp.

Comment: tried, but not working

Answer (score 50):

Seeing I am using a local environment I can safely disable SSL, which i did using the following:

```
$guzzleClient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(array( 'curl' => array( CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false, ), ));
$client->setHttpClient($guzzleClient);
```

Where `$client` is my Google_Client().

Comment: Yep, quick fix for local testing. Thanks for saving me hours ! :-)

Comment: this works in an example.

Comment: Thanks helped me with spark post guzzle adapter thing thanks @Sjors

Answer (score 31):

I work with xamps nothing of the above did work for me

I tried this and it worked

1. open `vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php`

and change this

```
$conf[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST] = 2;
$conf[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = true;
```

to this

```
$conf[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST] = 0;
$conf[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = FALSE;
```

it's a temporary solution if you updated this file the changes will lost

Comment: This helped me. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Again, this is a temporal solution. How can we pass parameters from our code such that it reaches there and disables the parameter?

Answer (score 30):

```
$guzzleClient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['verify' => false]);
```

Guzzle version 6

You could refer to Guzzle Docs at

http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#verify

Answer (score 5):

for the essence of development and testing, You have two options to a quick fix

> 1. Use

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$request = $client->request('GET',$url, ['verify' => false]); //where $url is your http address
```

> 2. follow @Pham Huy Anh answer's above then do this

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$request = $client->request('GET',$url, ['verify' => 'C:\xampp\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem']);
```

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: by doing `['verify' => false]` worked for me

Answer (score 1):

PCI-DSS 3.1 requires all SSL to only TLS 1.2 so a lot of providers are simply turning everything but TLS 1.2 off. I ran into this type of issue where CURL saw the failure to downgrade handshakes as a failure to verify the SSL certificate. Try finding where your code is doing the CURL call and add this line (be sure to replace `$ch` with whatever CURL handle your code uses)

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);  // Force TLS 1.2
```

Comment: how doI find the CURL handle my code uses? I run locally with a WAMPserver

Comment: is curl_init() a proper way? Setting the SSLVERSION to 6 doesn't solve the problem. Setting SSL_VERIFYPEER to false doesn't work either.

Comment: There will be a line in your code using `curl_init();` to initialize the CURL request. If setting TLS 1.2 doesn't work I'm not sure what else could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

it also worked for me by downloading the cert from the 
 link https://gist.github.com/VersatilityWerks/5719158/download
then 
save it in C:\xampp\php\extras\ssl
then edit php.ini. To get Php.ini quickly see the figure below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VqOo.png)

Then STOP and reStart your apache again. it worked well !!!

Answer (score -3):

```
$guzzleClient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['verify' => false]);
```

Comment: This appears to be identical to the code in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40623254/1575353) by lijnma... it doesn't appear to add anything beyond it...