# Google API setting environment variable

Tags: php, api, google-api, google-vision

When I load my application I get this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException' with message 'Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information' in C:\xampp\htdocs\CarLookup\vendor\google\cloud-core\RequestWrapper.php:253
```

I am trying to follow this: [Google Vision Doc](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/libraries)

I have run the command: `composer require google/cloud-vision`

Then on the Client Libary it is saying I have to set up a Client Library? I have done this with all he correct things then it says to-:

> Next, provide the credentials to your application code by setting the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to point to the JSON file you downloaded in the previous step.

And the execute this: `set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=<path_to_service_account_file>`

Where I am stuck is, where do I execute this, how do I set the environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

So, once you generate the JSON credentials you add this to your PHP script.

```
putenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=./my-project-e024c2b175e0.json");
```

It will then show another error about SSL certificate error...

Proceed here: [cURL error 60: SSL certificate prblm: unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35638497/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-prblm-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)