# Google OAuth2 authentication on Symfony 6 app on virtual local host "invalid_request"

Tags: php, google-oauth, symfony6

I have to run a project made long time ago by someone who left my compagny. This project is a Symfony 6 app developped with a Wamp server. On this app, you can login using your Google Account. But, when the developer left the compagny, she doesn't give access to her Google App on the Google Console, with the client ID and client secret used for the project. Then, I have to recreate the app and regenerate new client ID and new client secret. But, when I try to login with Google, I have an "invalid_request" error on the Google Loggin screen.

Full message is:

> You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy for keeping apps secure.
>
> You can let the app developer know that this app doesn't comply with one or more Google validation rules.
>
> Error 400: invalid_request

Error details give me this: "redirect_uri=http://random-quizz/connect/google/check"

My app run on virtual host created by Wamp, so the URL is not http://localhost/, but http://random-quizz/.

When I tried to put "http://random-quizz/" on the Authorized JavaScript origins parameters, it gives me the error "Invalid Origin: must end with a public top-level domain (such as .com or .org).". Putting "http://localhost/" is accepted, but doesn't work either.

I tried all of this :
Authorized JavaScript origins
http://localhost
http://localhost:8000

Authorized redirect URIs
http://localhost/connect/google/check
http://localhost
http://localhost:8000/connect/google/check

Nothing works. I'm completely new at this kind of things (Google OAuth2), so I don't really understand what can I do to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by edited my virtual host to be http://localhost on port 8081.
Also got error with curl certificate, solved with https://stackoverflow.com/a/40487704/16432086.