# XAMPP Error "GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException"

Tags: php, symfony

I am encountering error when I run the below command on command prompt (symfony installer):

```
 >> php -r "file_put_contents('symfony', file_get_contents('https://symfony.com/installer'));"
```

Then i created symfony project with below command

```
  >> php symfony new myProject
```

I am facing the below error even though in Netbeans:

```
[GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException]
  cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822686/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate

Comment: I am getting this issue in command prompt when i download the symfony application, do you have any idea about this problem.?

Comment: @k0pernikus, Thanks for Reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming On windows

XAMPP server

similar for other environment - download and extract for cacert.pem here (a clean file format/data)

I would recommend using the cacert.pem from the official curl-page: curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

put it here

```
C:\xampp\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem
```

in your php.ini put this line in this section:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; php.ini Options  ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

curl.cainfo = "C:\xampp\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"
```

restart your webserver/apache

This message is coming because of your PHP version. If it is upper from PHP 5.5 then coming this error because of PHP 5.6 new feature. PHP 5.6 check certificates if you are using cURL.