# cURL error 60: SSL certificate in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, curl, laravel-5

**Full Error**

`RequestException in CurlFactory.php line 187: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)`

**Scenario**

Before anyone points me to these two laracasts answers: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate/replies/52954

I've already looked at them and that's why I'm here.

The problem I have is that now I have the cacert.pem file BUT it doesn't make sense where to put it, the answers indicate to place the file in my xampp directory and change my `php.ini` file but I'm not using xampp for anything, I'm using Laravel's artisan server to run my project.

If xampp is not in use, where should I place this file? Moreover, why would an accepted answer be to place it in my xampp directory? I dont understand.

**My Exact Question**

Where do I place the `cacert.pem` file to stop this error in laravel 5.4?

Comment: Don't use the laravel built-in web server to try to resolve this. It's an exercise in futility since you're also going to need to re-resolve the issue on the webserver you'll be using on production. Just install apache or something and install the certificate based on the requirements of apache.

Comment: @apokryfos I figured the problem out

Comment: Then do post the solution. It may help someone somewhere.

Comment: You can use `withOptions` method to turn verification off: `$res = Http::withOptions(['verify' => false])->get('ur-api-endpoint');`

Comment: For those who have browsers that block historical URL (`curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem`), you can use the most recent URL from same people there > **[curl.se/ca/cacert.pem](https://curl.se/ca/cacert.pem)**

Answer (score 194, accepted):

**Do not ever** modify files in the `vendor/` folder. Ever. They can and will be overwritten on the next composer update you run.

**Here is my Solution for WampServer**

I am using PHP 7.1.9 for my WampServer, so change `7.1.9` in the example below to the version number you are currently using.

1. Download this file: http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
2. Place this file in the `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.1.9` folder
3. Open `php.ini`and find this line:

`;curl.cainfo`

Change it to:

`curl.cainfo = "C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.1.9\cacert.pem"`

*Make sure you remove the semicolon at the beginning of the line.*

Save changes to `php.ini`, restart WampServer, and you're good to go!

Comment: It works, and I also think, that this is so important: DON'T TOUCH the ```vendor/```  folder.

Comment: This feels like the right way to fix the problem, but somehow it does not work. I have php 7.1.11

Comment: And just to be extra clear: it works for IIS setups as well (not only Wamp). The focus is really enabling the certificate.

Comment: Note that there are several versions of `php.ini` in the Wamp environment. This solution may lead to use the version stored within the current php version directory. Actually, it may not be the one loaded by Wamp. Sounds better to use Wamp Menu > PHP > php.ini. which may lead  to the version within the Apache directory, that is actually loaded.

Comment: This worked. Can you briefly explain/describe what is going on here? Thank you.

Comment: uOowww man!! thanks thanks very much! this another solution --> `$client = $client ?: new Client(['verify' => false]);` not work!!!

Comment: i have done all the mentioned steps but now it is showing this error AWS HTTP error: cURL error 77: error setting certificate verify locations

Comment: The cacert.pem link is broken. I think that the correct one is curl.se/ca/cacert.pem

Comment: The given solution worked for me. correct cacert.pem link is https://curl.se/ca/cacert.pem

Comment: In my case i use Wamp Server 3.2.6. You need to do the same but in phpForApache.ini. unless it won't work.

Comment: Thanks, this still worked for me on Laravel 8.x and in the year 2022 while using PHP 7.4.0. LOL

Answer (score 31):

A quick solution but insecure (***not recommended***).

Using ***cURL***:

```
Set CURLOPT_SSL_VERIYPEER to false
```

Using ***Guzzle***: Set verify to false, for example

```
$client->request('GET', 'https://somewebsite.com', ['verify' => false]);
```

Comment: thanks
this is working for me laravel 7+

```$res = \Http::withOptions(['verify' => false])->get("http://somewebsite.com");
```

Answer (score 19):

You can use `GuzzleHttp\Client`:

`$client = new Client(['verify' => false]);`

Answer (score 9):

- Solution suggested by some users to make changes to `\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Client.php` file is the worst advice, as manual changes made to vendor folder are overwritten if you run `composer update` command.
- Solution suggested by [Jeffrey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094842/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-in-laravel-5-4#answer-50184562) is a dirty, shorthand fix but not recommended in production applications.
- Solution suggested by [kjdion84](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094842/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-in-laravel-5-4#answer-49071524) is perfect if you have access to `php.ini` file on web server. That is, to update `curl.cainfo="<absolute_path_here>\cacert.pem"` in `php.ini` file.
- In case you are using Shared Hosting, it may not be possible to edit `php.ini` file.

---

**When you don't have access to `php.ini` file (e.g. Shared Hosting)**

1. Download this file: http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem or https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html
2. Place this file in the root folder of your Laravel project.
3. Add `verify` key to `GuzzleHttp\Client` constructor with its value as path to `cacert.pem` file.
4. Now depending on whether you are using core PHP or Laravel framework pick a solution from below.

**Solution 1**: Using PHP 5.5+ and GuzzleHttp 6.0+

```
// https://example.com/v1/current.json?key1=value1&key2=value2

$http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'base_uri' => 'https://example.com',
    'verify' => base_path('cacert.pem'),
]);

$response = $http->get('v1/current.json', [
    'query' => [
        'key1' => 'value1',
        'key2' => 'value2',
    ]
]);

$response = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
```

**Solution 2**: Using Laravel 5.7+ and GuzzleHttp 6.0+

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

// https://example.com/v1/current.json?key1=value1&key2=value2

$http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'base_uri' => 'https://example.com',
    'verify' => base_path('cacert.pem'),
]);

$response = Http::setClient($http)->get('v1/current.json', [
    'query' => [
        'key1' => 'value1',
        'key2' => 'value2',
    ]
]);

$response = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
```

Comment: Working in Laravel 9.19 with Guzzle 7.5 and PHP 8.0.2

Answer (score 7):

This was stressfull to figure out but here is the exact answer for people using laravel and have this problem.

My exact application versions are...

> Laravel: 5.4
>
> Guzzlehttp: 6.2
>
> Laravel Socialite: 3.0

Download a fresh copy of this curl certificate from this link: https://gist.github.com/VersatilityWerks/5719158/download

Save the file in this path starting from the base root of your laravel application `vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/cacert.pem`

next in that same directory open up `RequestOptions.php` and scroll down to the constant called `CERT` and change it to this `const CERT = 'cacert.pem';` and this should fix it all.

**EDIT**

As people are pointing out you should never edit the vendor folder, this was just a quick fix for an application I was building in my spare time. It wasn't anything majorly important like an application for my company or anything, use this method at your own risk! Please check out the other answers if you need something more concrete.

Comment: It didn't seem to work for me. What php version did you use and what localhost wamp(64/32) or xamp?

Comment: My xampp at the time was the latest php7 version, I can't remember exactly which one i used sorry

Comment: +1 thanks a lot, I tried all the other solutions but this was the only one that worked.. just jump into the vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src folder and do a "wget http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem" to get a fresh copy

Comment: But I heard a loooot of times that I should not mess around vendor

Comment: @Nikonah then don't, i should mention this was just a quick fix that worked for me. not sure of any alternatives

Answer (score 4):

For php version ^8.1 in wampserver

1. Download--> https://curl.se/ca/cacert.pem.
2. Place the cacert.pem file inside C:\wamp64\bin\php\php8.1.0.
3. Open php.ini and find this line:
   ;curl.cainfo

Change it to:

curl.cainfo = "C:\wamp64\bin\php\php8.1.0\cacert.pem"

Make sure you remove the semicolon at the beginning of the line.

Save changes to php.ini, restart WampServer64, and you're good to go!

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem while running Valet and attempting to make an api from one site in valet to another.
Note that i'm working in OSX.
I found the solution here: https://github.com/laravel/valet/issues/460
In short you have to copy the valet pem to the system CA bundle.
Just run this:

```
cp /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem.bak && cat ~/.config/valet/CA/LaravelValetCASelfSigned.pem >> /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem
```

Answer (score 3):

I was sending a request from domain **X** to **Y**, my problem was with the certificate used on the domain Y (it wasn't a self-signed cert btw), the domain belonged to me & I had the certificate, so the quick fix was to use the domain Y's certificate on domain X's application:

On domain **X**:

- Using Laravel 7 HTTP wrapper:

  `\Http::withOptions(['verify' => 'path-to-domain-Y-certificate']);`
- Using guzzle:

  `new GuzzleHttp\Client(['verify' => 'path-to-domain-Y-certificate']);`

OR you could just contact your SSL provider to resolve the issue.

**Note**: Storing your domain's certificate in another system isn't a secure method, use this method only if you can ensure your certificate's security.

I haven't found what was wrong with the certificate, no browser seemed to have a problem with it, the only problem was generated on laravel using curl.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me in development with laravel 8 using the default server started by running:

```
php artisan serve
```

The solution for me was similar to other answers that require you to download `cacert.pem` and edit `php.ini` file. But since I was not using Wamp, I checked the `path` in my environment variables to find which php installation windows defaulted to and made the changes there.

Answer (score 2):

I use laragon server and I faced to the same problem. I downloaded ssl certificate from http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and paste it in C:/laragon/etc/ssl/
(if cacert.pem already  exists replace it with new one).
restart server and everything is fine

Answer (score 1):

We can set path based on this article on Medium.com [How to fix cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem](https://medium.com/@narendravaghela/how-to-fix-curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-problem-80e7dafafa57)

Steps to follow:

1. Open http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
2. Copy the entire page and save it as a “cacert.pem”
3. Open your php.ini file and insert or update the following line. curl.cainfo = " [pathtofile]cacert.pem"

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was because of **Zscaler**.

**Disabling (Turning Off)** `Zscaler Internet Security` fixed the issue and then I could install Laravel on my local machine.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/66366341/327862

> zscaler acts as an SSL proxy, enterprise requirement... it puts itself
> squarely between you and the outside world -- decrypts any outbound
> SSL traffic and re-encrypts it using a self-signed certificate -- or
> at least one signed by a non-trusted CA. So the inbound return SSL
> connection appears to be using a cert from an invalid CA and thus the
> error (that's my understanding)... getcomposer docs says it uses PHP
> settings... PHP says it uses the OS settings, also saying you
> shouldn't have to set this... see relevant link here:
> https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#cafile
>
> [Docker Windows Composer ZScaler SSL Certificate Verify Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61491995/docker-windows-composer-zscaler-ssl-certificate-verify-failed)

Answer (score 0):

Another one recently asked for the same problem and it's seems my answer was the solution for him.
Here was the post I mention : [URL Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42120301/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-in-laravel-5-3/42120524#42120524)

That's what I said :

> I'll be fully honest, I don't know anything about Laravel. But I had
>   the same problem, so as many other, on Symfony. And so as you I tried
>   many things without success.
>
> Finally, this solution worked for me :  [URL solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822686/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)
>
> It indicates that instead of a *certificate problem*, it could came
>   from a **environnement non-compatibility**. I used XAMPP instead of
>   WAMP and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it on my end by disabling `verify` completely when on debug setting since in this local scenario security is not an issue at all.

```php
$http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
            'base_uri' => config('services.passport.login_endpoint'),
            'verify' => config('app.debug') ? false : true,
            'defaults' => [
                'exceptions' => false,
            ]
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the following file in `vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php`

```php
$defaults = [
    'allow_redirects' => RedirectMiddleware::$defaultSettings,
    'http_errors'     => true,
    'decode_content'  => true,
    'verify'          => false, //  By default this value will be true
    'cookies'         => false
];
```

May be security issue was there, but it will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl.cainfo = "C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.1.9\cacert.pem"
```

I had resolved my problem with wamp.

Comment: Where exactly do you paste this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem in my case was that i was connected to a wifi network that was blocking the api i'm accessing. When i connected to the internet using mobile data the issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i'm facing this when do connection to the firebase, the cause was as simple as this:
i add cacert.pem file to php ext folder, then call it by remove ; tag for `;curl.cainfo =`  in php.ini, i fill with the path where i place the cacert.pem file just like @kjdion84 explanation,  **then**
in **env** file, i just needed to move `FIREBASE_CREDENTIAL` above `FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL`, and the problem was solved. hope this help to who's in same case with me.
[image: env]

Answer (score -3):

for Laravel: The 5 steps below will be helpful

- update version to `Guzzlehttp: 5.2`
- find the file under `\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Client.php`
- edit default settings to

  protected function getDefaultOptions() {
      $settings = [
      'allow_redirects' => true,
      'exceptions'      => true,
      'decode_content'  => true,
      'verify'          => getcwd() .'/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/cacert.pem'
      ];
  }
- download latest file cacert.pem from  `http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem`   and place under `/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/`

Comment: You should never touch or edit files in the vendor folder.

Comment: modifying vendor file is a terrible idea