# Laravel Socialite cURL error 60: SSL certificate

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, curl

I am using Laravel Socialite in my app. I am using `Login with Google`! However, I am getting this `cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate` error.

I went through this: [cURL error 60: SSL certificate: unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822686/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate]) and did the exact steps but still, it won't work.

I tried this in `php.ini`:

```
curl.cainfo="C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.4\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"
```

Here's my `api.php`:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function() {
    Route::get('login/google', function() {
        return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
    });
    Route::get('login/google/callback', function() {
        $user = Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->user();
        return $user->token();
    });
});
```

I am using `php artisan serve` to serve my application. Please help!

Comment: Laravel not uses wamp server...  try this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094842/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-in-laravel-5-4

Comment: @EtibarRustemzade Don't say that you are suggesting me to touch the vendor files!

Comment: Which php.ini did you change? If your using `php artisan serve`, you might want to check where your binary is, https://github.com/symfony/process/blob/master/PhpExecutableFinder.php#L36 if you changed the wrong ini file it wont work.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I just did: `Click Wampserver icon>PHP>php.ini`

Comment: @Sanjay I think you missunderstood, look at the code in the link, `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.4\php.exe` might not be used by `php artisan serve`, but instead it fallsback to php cli server, if so changing your "php.ini" file might not make a difference as it's not the one used.. Can you run `phpinfo()` in your php code?

Comment: Yes, I am able to run `phpinfo()` and it says the version is `PHP Version 7.2.4`! Also there is `Loaded Configuration File: C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.4\php.ini`!

Comment: Oh yes! The changes are not saved there. Trying it from there now!

Comment: @LawrenceCherone That worked! Thank you so much. You are life savior!

Comment: np, glad it helped

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I guess you should write the answer for it! You know the first glance goes to the Answers section rather than the comments section.