# How do I get azure ad auth up and running?

Tags: laravel, authentication, azure-active-directory

After searching for days I still dont know how to get my laravel web app to work with azure ad auth.
I want the people to SSO via azure ad. How is this done and where can I start ?
Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad#-configure-with-express-settings) to configure your web app to use Azure AD login.

**Note**: In step 4, I recommend you to create a new AD App(app registration), not `select an existing app`, when using the first one, azure will help you configure some settings automatically, it can save unnecessary trouble.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did as you told me to and it seems to work. Currently trying to debug because im getting this error: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html , any idea?

Comment: and yes, i did already upload a new cacert.pem to my ssl folder and updated the php.ini , restarted the webserver, even the computer.

Comment: @Coderz9 Did you login successfully with your AAD account?

Comment: That's when I get the curl error. Maybe because I'm on localhost?

Comment: I'll comment in a couple of hours my code and what I tried if I can't get it to work. Ty though already for the help

Comment: @Coderz9 I am afraid I can't help you more. Because the AAD authentication is before your code, e.g. even if there is nothing in your web app, the authentication will also work, you can login successfully. I am not familiar with laravel, so I recommend you to ask a new question about the error.

Comment: @Coderz9 And I see there are many posts about the error, you could check them if helpful, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094842/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-in-laravel-5-4

Comment: getting a redirect error now, i created a new post about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58912031/microsoft-azure-ad-auth-invalid-request-the-provided-value-for-the-input-param maybe youre able to help :x