# Calling HTTPS request from laravel to external API

Tags: laravel, ssl, ssl-certificate, guzzle

I am developing app to get `json` data from other site and show in html table in `laravel`.
I use Guzzle to send request.([stackoverflow question and finally use Guzzle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22355828/doing-http-requests-from-laravel-to-an-external-api))
when i called request based on `http` to External API,it's show me correct data!
my **problem** is:
when i call the `HTTPS` link to get data in laravel,it goes to `ssl` error.
some of API addresses just work in `HTTPS`,

```
cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

what can i do?

Answer (score 1):

Solved!
this is my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094842/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-in-laravel-5-4)

```
1-Download this file: http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
2-Place this file in the C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.1.9 folder
3-Open php.iniand find this line:
```