# How to set GuzzleHttp verify to false in Laravel app

Tags: php, laravel, curl, client

I want to use a package (Cloudinary) to upload an image, after all the setup, I am getting an error[image]

This is the code from Cloudinary documentation,

```
        $uploadedFileUrl = cloudinary()->upload($request->file('profile_image')->getRealPath())->getSecurePath();
```

So I can't set Guzzle verification to false in this way

```
    $client = new Client([
        'base_uri' => ''
,       'headers' => $headers,
        'verify' => false,
        'VERIFY_PEER' => true,
        'http_errors' => false,
    ]);
```

My problem is, how do I set Guzzle Http Client verification to false, generally in the application

Comment: did you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50184562/7574023)

Comment: @boolfalse, I tried that, but still the same error

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add any Guzzlehttp's options within Laravel app you can just use the `withOptions` method.
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client#guzzle-options

```
Http::withOptions([
    'verify' => false,
])->get('http://whatever.com');
```