# I can't hit google recapcha api to get response. Captcha is v-2

Tags: google-api, laravel-8, recaptcha

```
     use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http; 

  
$response = Http::asForm()->post('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', [
        'secret' => '6LftPCIdAAAAAPD5Md-fahgg3sj0SCUhV9qC5e9B',  
        'response' => request('Response')
    ])->json();
    return $response;
```

The error i get is:

GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify in file D:\CODE\flowlence-api\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 211

I have tried to do this but it didn't work
[cURL error 60: SSL certificate in Laravel 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094842/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-in-laravel-5-4)

And I dont have xampp or wamp.

Thanks.

Comment: Response is token that recaptcha created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it.
Since I don't use Xampp or Wamp i went to PHP\v7.4\extras\ssl and there I have pasted cacert.pem

And in php.ini I have found curl.cainfo = C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v7.4\extras\ssl\cacert.pem and i uncommented it by removing ;

restarted local host and it works.