# Uncaught exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException' with message 'cURL error 60

Tags: php, google-api, google-signin

I tried google oauth php on my localhost and got this error!What can I do

Uncaught exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException' with message 
**'cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate** (see

> http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)' in
>   C:\wamp\www\google\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php

on line 187

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cURL error 60: SSL certificate: unable to get local issuer certificate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822686/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)

Answer (score 0):

1. Download ca fiile "curl http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem -o cacert.pem"
2. My file "cacert.pem" move to "/wwwroot/ca/cacert.pem"
3. Open file php.ini, enable openssl, and find "openssl.cafile", set "openssl.cafile=/wwwroot/ca/cacert.pem"
4. Restart web server(nginx/apache) or reopen terminal.
5. Enjoy.

Comment: don't you have to do this every few months or the connections will fail when that file becomes invalid?