# Error sending SMS to user using laravel and nexmo

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, curl, vonage

I'm using laravel to write a SMS application. So I' am also using the Nexmo API, I followed [the tutorial on github](https://github.com/Nexmo/nexmo-laravel),

But, when I try to send it on localhost. I got a curl SSL error:

```
RequestException in Promise.php line 135: <br/>
    cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate 
    (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cURL error 60: SSL certificate: unable to get local issuer certificate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822686/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)

Comment: what does that mean