# cURL error 60 - SSL certificate problem - unable to get local issuer

Tags: php, symfony, ssl, curl

PHP version: 5.6

Problem: I get an error:

```
    cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate.
```

Steps I tried to solve this issue:

- `php -r "readfile('https://symfony.com/installer');" > symfony`

  1. Download a file with the updated list of certificates from https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem.
  2. Set path in `php.ini`

     `curl.cainfo =D:\xampp_tomact\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem
     openssl.cafile=D:\xampp_tomact\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem`
  3. Apache restart
  4. Then I tried with

     ```
     php symfony new my_project_name
     ```

I have taken help from links

http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html

[cURL error 60: SSL certificate: unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822686/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)

But none of the solution worked in xampp windows.
Please suggest

Steps I tried again

1. `d:\xampp\htdocs> php -r "readfile('http://symfony.com/installer');" > symfony`
2. `d:\xampp\htdocs\projects> php symfony`
3. `symfony new my_project_name`.

Error after executing the third command above:

```
    cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer
```

Still no solution for this bug while installing symfony.

I also followed symfony docs

[image: Symfony docs picture]

[image: CMD commands picture]

Last solution I also tried:

[PHP - SSL certificate error: unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858351/php-ssl-certificate-error-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)

But it also did not work.

```
 xampp version 3.2.2
```

Comment: Why do you want to use SSL locally ?

Comment: i want to install symfony2 locally

Comment: When do you get this error ?

Comment: hi coil i got error when ran :php symfony new my_project_name

Comment: Look at the suggested answer and retry.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cURL error 60: SSL certificate: unable to get local issuer certificate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822686/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)

Comment: no coild this duplicate i have already tried but nothing works for me i think php 5.5 has bug with curl & ssl

Comment: Try replacing https by http

Comment: same error i tried to download symfony through http

Answer (score 5):

After lots of struggle I found why symfony cannot be downloaded

1. XAMPP version 3.2.2 downgraded XAMPP vr 3.2.1
2. Download `cacert.pem` file from  https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem.
3. `php.ini` line 989 put this `curl.cainfo ="D:\xamppNew\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"`
4. Restart apachae again.
5. Message: `symfony is being downloaded`.

In my case xampp 3.2.2 was creating problem. So beware from XAMPP 3.2.2. It has some bugs which apache should fix.

***Finally I can say this was xampp problem i.e new version in which tomcat is installed.***

Answer (score 3):

```sh
user@DESKTOP-HE0OTN5 MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/symphart
$ composer diagnose
You are running Composer with SSL/TLS protection disabled.
Checking composer.json: WARNING
require.composer/package-versions-deprecated : exact version constraints (1.11.99.1) should be avoided if the package follows semantic versioning<br>  
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK 
Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking https connectivity to packagist: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] curl error 60 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
Composer is configured to disable SSL/TLS protection. This will leave remote HTTPS requests vulnerable to Man-In-The-Middle attacks.
Checking github.com rate limit: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] curl error 60 while downloading https://api.github.com/rate_limit: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys:
Tags Public Key Fingerprint: 57815BA2 7E54DC31 7ECC7CC5 573090D0  87719BA6 8F3BB723 4E5D42D0 84A14642
Dev Public Key Fingerprint: 4AC45767 E5EC2265 2F0C1167 CBBB8A2B  0C708369 153E328C AD90147D AFE50952
OK
Checking composer version: Warning: Accessing getcomposer.org over http which is an insecure protocol.
OK
Composer version: 2.0.12
PHP version: 7.4.16
PHP binary path: C:\Program Files\php-7.4.16\php.exe
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1i  8 Dec 2020
cURL version: 7.70.0 libz 1.2.11 ssl OpenSSL/1.1.1i
zip: extension present, unzip present<br>
```

If you are running with this issue i can help you....

You just need to remove some line of code from your composer.json file of your project file from c:\xampp\htdocs\symphart(yourProjectFile)

```json
 "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true,
        "disable-tls": true, 
        "secure-http": false
```

You just need to remove this two line of code from your composer.json file
And you'll find this result

```sh
user@DESKTOP-HE0OTN5 MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/symphart
$ composer diagnose
Checking composer.json: WARNING
require.composer/package-versions-deprecated : exact version constraints (1.11.99.1) should be avoided if the package follows semantic versioning
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking https connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking github.com rate limit: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys:
Tags Public Key Fingerprint: 57815BA2 7E54DC31 7ECC7CC5 573090D0  87719BA6 8F3BB723 4E5D42D0 84A14642
Dev Public Key Fingerprint: 4AC45767 E5EC2265 2F0C1167 CBBB8A2B  0C708369 153E328C AD90147D AFE50952
OK
Checking composer version: OK
Composer version: 2.0.12
PHP version: 7.4.16
PHP binary path: C:\Program Files\php-7.4.16\php.exe
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1i  8 Dec 2020
cURL version: 7.70.0 libz 1.2.11 ssl OpenSSL/1.1.1i
zip: extension present, unzip present
```

If you are ok with it you can try this out