# Symfony project in netbeans: cURL error 60

Tags: php, symfony, ssl, curl, netbeans

Whenever I create a new php project in netbeans that use the Symfony2 framework, it always responds with an error message which says:

> [GuzzleHttp\Ring\Exception\RingException]
>     cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

I have already tried the solution written on Symfony's webpage with the cacert.pem file, also tried to move it to the extras/ssl folder, but none of this worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cURL error 60: SSL certificate: unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822686/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)

Comment: I think that there is no relation with your cURL error

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think that there is no relation between netbeans and the error.

next, try to add option `'verify' => false,` to the **guzzle client**

```
<?php

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client([
        'verify' => false,
]);
```