# How can I use CURL in PHP to handle a 301 (Moved Permanently) error when accessing an API?

Tags: php, curl

I have to access an API using a GET request but the result is:

> 301 Moved Permanently.

Here is my code:

```
$curl = curl_init();
    $url="https://xxx.yyy.com/zzz/v1.0";
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                    "authorization: Bearer sadhuUasjhda"
                      ),
                    ));

    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
      echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
      echo $response;
    }

    print_r($result);exit;
```

I've read that this problem can be solve by adding `CURLOPT_POSTREDIR`, but that's only worked when I used POST.

I've tried to use `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` but I get a different problem, the result is like

> CURL Error #:SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate.

FYI, I'm using Windows and XAMPP. And then I tried following instructions on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822686/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate) but the result is still the same.

Comment: Have you tried using CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false?

Comment: hey it works, thank you so much  :) @RendyEkoPrastiyo

Comment: Capitalized "I" and some other edits for clarity/English.

Answer (score 1):

thanks to Rendy Eko Prastiyo, the solution is add CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER set to false and CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION set to true, so the code is

```
$curl = curl_init();
$url="https://xxx.yyy.com/zzz/v1.0";
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                "authorization: Bearer sadhuUasjhda"
                  ),
                ));

$result = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}

print_r($result);exit;
```