# lighttpd redirect from custom HTTP port 81 to HTTPS port 443

Tags: https, lighttpd

I have the following configuration

```
$SERVER["socket"] == ":81" {
#$HTTP["scheme"] == "http" {
    $HTTP["host"] =~ ".*" {
        url.redirect = (".*" => "https://%0$0")
    }
}
```

As far as i see: `%0` expands to `serverip:81`. 
**So i need to get rid of `:81` from `%0`. How?**

But it leads to the redirection from HTTP port 81 to *https://serverip:81* and then fails with `SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL`.

Answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/62099076/3743145:

> ```
>  * LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to 192.168.144.1:81
> ```
>
> The error is SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL and this has nothing to do with certificate validation. In fact, a closer look at what you are doing shows that you are redirecting from plain HTTP on port 81 to HTTPS on the same port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

```
$HTTP["scheme"] == "http" {
    $HTTP["host"] =~ "(.*)(:[0-9]+|)$" {  ## %1 contains hostname without port
        url.redirect = (".*" => "https://%1$0")
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @kyb, I tried your solution but it says Unable to connect. I am using localhost on port 8081.

Comment: @Preeti please create a Q with detailed logs from server and from client, than tag me here.