# PHP cURL error 60

Tags: php, ssl, curl

Yes I've seen the many questions about this, in fact I already had this problem and solved it last year. This time for some reason the solution (adding https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) doesn't work.

The server (my company's) is a node.js app, I registered the server private key, server crt, and the root and intermediate certificates (I think?), the names are `DigiCertCA.crt` and `TrustedRoot.crt`. The client is a PHP script making a cURL connection. It had been working fine after I added cacert.pem to php.ini. Recently my company renewed the SSL certificates, and around the same time the client PHP script (another company's) was moved to a production server from dev. Then the SSL broke again.

The website looks fine when opened with chrome (secure https, not broken). Here is the PHP script, simplified to demonstrate the problem. I tried adding the cacert.pem both through php.ini and curl_setopt, with no success. This is running on my local development machine, Windows 10 with xampp 5.6.3

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://example.com'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'D:/xampp/php/extras/ssl/cacert.pem');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);
$content = trim(curl_exec($ch));
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    $content = 'ERROR -> ' . curl_errno($ch) . ': ' . curl_error($ch);
} 
curl_close($ch);
print $content;
```

Error message:

```
60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Additional info:

The error message for the production PHP script is different actually, there it says

```
curl: (60) Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized.
```

I also tried using curl to access other subdomains using my company's certificates and they all give the same error 60. While accessing `https://twitter.com` is OK

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cURL error 60: SSL certificate: unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822686/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);` try once

Comment: @Alive to Die Not an option, I don't want to turn off verifypeer as that would make https useless

Comment: @PankajMakwana I've tried that, as I stated in my question, doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

you have a mistake I think

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

you have kept this `true`, so it seems to be the issue

Comment: That does not solve my problem at all, it just turns off cert verification

Comment: what happens when you remove curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'D:/xampp/php/extras/ssl/cacert.pem'); from the code?

Comment: Nothing, same error 60 as before, I've added additional info to my question

Comment: I hope you are not trying to curl https://example.com as the domain does not exist with the ssl

Comment: No no, that's just a placeholder, I curl my company web server, but I don't think they'd be pleased if I write the url here

Comment: what happens when you directly hit that url? you get the output?

Comment: With browser - OK; With powershell curl - OK; With PHP curl - ERROR