# Error GuzzleHttp cURL error 60: SSL certificate

Tags: php

Im trying to use the Google API, however, when I run it it shows me the following error:

```
GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: u
    nable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl
    -errors.html) in C:\wamp64\www\apigmail\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\Cur
    lFactory.php on line 187
```

Im using WAMP -Server PHP v 7.0.13

Comment: Normally this is an error on the server side try chane your request URL to http://. If that works log an issue with google

Answer (score 7):

Now you can use :

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['verify' => false ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to read your error code :)
Its simple you have some SSL errors because your localhost enviroment cant get the data, because you didnt have any SSL certificate.

But here is an solution of your problem in an another thread:
[cURL error 60: SSL certificate: unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822686/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)

Comment: ok i do this and now have the next ERROR :
invalid token format Google\Client.php

Comment: yes for some APIs you need an API-KEY to get an oauth token.

Comment: but i have an API KEY and CREDENTIALS

Comment: if you work on a local enviroment you have to get a valid API KEY for this "domain". If localhost (127.0.0.1) isn't set by google for your API key this didn't work.
I use this guide and php sdk to get my solution, it works fine for me https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

Comment: Well... one thing, it would be nice if you mark my answer as correct. Since she helped with your described problem. For the following problem, this topic would also be inappropriate because the error is triggered by something else.

Answer (score 1):

you have to add
`\GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::VERIFY => false` to the client config:

```
$this->client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'base_uri'                          => 'someAccessPoint',
    \GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::HEADERS => [
        'User-Agent' => 'some-special-agent',
    ],
    'defaults'                          => [
        \GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::CONNECT_TIMEOUT => 5,
        \GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::ALLOW_REDIRECTS => true,
    ],
    \GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::VERIFY  => false,
]);
```

it will set `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` in the `CurlFactory::applyHandlerOptions()` method

```
$conf[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST] = 0;
$conf[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;
```

From the [GuzzleHttp documentation](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html)

> **verify**
>
> Describes the SSL certificate verification behavior of a request.
>
> - Set to true to enable SSL certificate verification and use the default CA bundle > provided by operating system.
> - Set to false to disable certificate verification (this is insecure!).
> - Set to a string to provide the path to a CA bundle to enable verification using a custom certificate.