# cURL error 60: SSL certificate prob...: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl, curl, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to make a request to an external api from my wordpress but I get this error:

> cURL error 60: SSL certificate prob...: unable to get local issuer
>   certificate

```
$response = wp_remote_post($url, array(
  'headers'   => array('Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8'),
  'body'      => json_encode($data)
));
```

I already researched and saw many people complaining about the same error but I still could not solve anything with the solutions I found.

I have my wordpress v4.8.3 installed inside Plesk Onyx 17.5.3 with Let's Encrypt ssl cetificate.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: See this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822686/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate

Comment: Thanks for helping me Yuxel but after several attempts I found that the problem was in the external site ssl certificate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cURL error 60: SSL certificate: unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822686/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)