# cURL error 60 with laravel 5.5

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, api, curl

When trying to connect my Laravel app with Facebook app API I get this error

```
cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate 
(see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

I tried all this solutions :

- I downloaded the file `cacert.pem`, place it inside my php file and edited the `php.ini` curl.cainfo = "the path of cacer.pem"
- I edited my file `config/session.php`  'domain' => localhost

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This link might be helpful:

[cURL error 60: SSL certificate: unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822686/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)

FWIW, When I program with curl in C I typically need to provide a "crt" file, as follows:

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "ca-bundle.crt");