# How can I curl deepcrawl?

Tags: php, json, laravel, curl

My Deepcrawl crawl only give null value.

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.deepcrawl.com/accounts/00000/projects/195334/crawls/1306396/reports/thin_pages_basic");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('X-Auth-Token:Private'));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output2 = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch); 

$results = json_decode($server_output2);
```

To create a session you first need to manually generate an API Key. This is a key/value pair that can be generated in the API Access page. When you click Generate New API Key, a popup will be displayed with the API Key Value and in the table of Active Keys you can find the API Key ID. This is then sent via Basic Authentication in a POST call to the sessions route.

```
curl -X POST -u '123:abcdef' https://api.deepcrawl.com/sessions
{
"token":"abcdef123",
"_user_href":"/users/example-user",
...
}
```

The token returned from the call to sessions is then passed to all API calls as the X-Auth-Token header:

```
curl -X GET -H 'X-Auth-Token:' https://api.deepcrawl.com/accounts/1/projects
```

Can someone explain me further about the authentication of deepcrawl? How can I able to curl it using `X-Auth-Token` only. Sorry for my bad English. Thank you

Comment: What does `echo curl_error();` tell you?

Comment: @delboy1978uk curl_error(): supplied resource is not a valid cURL handle resource

Comment: Sorry! `curl_error($ch)`

Comment: Same buddy. Don't know why.

Comment: do it before your `curl_close($ch)` line

Comment: just blank nothing happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181232/discussion-between-christian-gallarmin-and-delboy1978uk).

Comment: chats blocked in here.

Comment: Have a read here https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

Comment: Operation completed without any errors I got this but json_decode() still null then.

Answer (score 2):

CURL may be tricky sometimes.

When I face problems with CURL I first try to do the same on command line, in this case it worked perfectly so we can reject there is any kind of problem on API or on CURL so we must assume the problem is on the php call.

When you get a NULL it's likely there is an error set on curl handler, you just need to look for it and bring it to screen:

```
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.deepcrawl.com/accounts/00000/projects/195334/crawls/1306396/reports/thin_pages_basic");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('X-Auth-Token:Private'));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $server_output2 = curl_exec ($ch);

    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        print curl_error($ch);
        die();
        // or whatever you might want to do with this error
       } 
    curl_close ($ch); 

    $results = json_decode($server_output2);
```

In this case the error was:

> SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822686/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate) you can see how to fix this problem, just need to add a valid CA cert to your php.ini (in the example cacert is used) like that:

> 1) Download the latest cacert.pem from https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
>
> 2) Add the following line to php.ini (if this is shared hosting and you don't have access to php.ini then you could add this to .user.ini in public_html)
>
> curl.cainfo="/path/to/downloaded/cacert.pem"