# Deepcrawl authencation curl response null?

Tags: php, laravel, curl

To authenticate API calls, you must first generate a session to get a token. Then you must send the session token as the value of the X-Auth-Token header to authenticate API calls.

To create a session you first need to manually generate an API Key. This is a key/value pair that can be generated in the API Access page. When you click Generate New API Key, a popup will be displayed with the API Key Value and in the table of Active Keys you can find the API Key ID. This is then sent via Basic Authentication in a POST call to the sessions route.

I followed this Api Documentation of deepcrawl already but what am I doing wrong?

I have `X-Auth-Token` and `API KEY ID` where should I put this?

```
$deephead = "X-Auth-Token: asdjasiojqoieuqiouwqpofoqwojeq"; 

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.deepcrawl.com/sessions");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $deephead);

// Get the response
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// Close cURL connection
curl_close($ch);

// Decode the response (Transform it to an Array)
$result = json_decode($response);

//debug the response
dd($result);
```

The I can't even get to `CURLOPT_GET` cause at my `post` I only get null value. Any idea/thoughts how can I fix this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DeepCrawl API](http://api-docs.deepcrawl.com/#/)

It looks like you are trying to generate a token, which it looks like you already have.

> To authenticate API calls, you must first generate a session to get a
>   token. Then you must send the session token as the value of the
>   X-Auth-Token header to authenticate API calls.
>
> To create a session you first need to manually generate an API Key.
>   This is a key/value pair that can be generated in the API Access page.
>   When you click Generate New API Key, a popup will be displayed with
>   the API Key Value and in the table of Active Keys you can find the API
>   Key ID. This is then sent via Basic Authentication in a POST call to
>   the sessions route.
>
> `curl -X POST -u '123:abcdef' https://api.deepcrawl.com/sessions { 
>   "token":"abcdef123",   "_user_href":"/users/example-user",   ... }`

Not the clearest, but it's right there.

```
$headers = [
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'accept: text/html'
];
$username='yourusername';
$password='supersecret';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.deepcrawl.com/sessions");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "root=1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

// Get the response
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// Close cURL connection
curl_close($ch);

// Decode the response (Transform it to an Array)
return json_decode($response);
```

That will return something like

```
{
  "token":"abcdef123",
  "_user_href":"/users/example-user",
  ...
}
```

Since you already have the token, you don't need ot hit session. you can just make your calls.

```
$headers = [
    'X-AUTH-TOKEN: your-api-key',
    'accept: text/html'
];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.deepcrawl.com/system_statuses");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

// Get the response
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// Close cURL connection
curl_close($ch);

// Decode the response (Transform it to an Array)
return json_decode($response);
```

Comment: Did they actually need user and password?

Comment: I've tried this command but same thing I only gets null value :/

Comment: Which endpoint are you hitting? If there is no data in you account there is no response.

Comment: I have data in my accounts. I also have 2 api key id with generated session tokens.

Comment: 6/7 are active right now in my account. That's weird

Comment: Try the last code block and see if that works. I have no data in my account and all the source above worked for me.

Comment: it works on https://api.deepcrawl.com/system_statuses but when i tried my accounts its null.

Comment: That's weird. I get a 401 when I do a terminal command with verbose and I copy and paste their provided command. It did work with my credentials and a session token, but not with my api key. I would start a ticket, because it sounds a little buggy to me.

Comment: Buddy, I tried to run the first block of your code and when I verified my token is different from my X-Auth-Token is that possible?

Comment: can you post your answer here at my bounty as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52521892/how-can-i-curl-deepcrawl/52641640#52641640

Comment: Sure thing, it's up