# laravel 5.7 cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, wamp

i am using this package for laravel 5.7

```
composer require ipecompany/smsirlaravel
```

all my links are working fine but the package admin panel link gives the ssl error .
i tried to download cacert.pem file and place it both on

```
C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.1.9\extras\ssl\cacert.pem
```

and

```
C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.27\bin\cacert.pem
```

but yet no luck with this error

```
cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

and i am using wamp 3.1.0 and php version 7.1.9 so any idea how this error can be solved ??

Comment: This problem is solved at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822686/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable check:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

**UPDATE**

ok, sorry, my bad, didn't noticed that you are using external package. This package uses Guzzle, to disable in Guzzle this check you need to add [this option](https://guzzle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/request-options.html?highlight=verify#verify).

As an option you need to create your own class and extend this `Ipecompany\Smsirlaravel\Smsirlaravel` class and override methods. The bad thing is that in each method of this class class creates new instance of GuzzleClient, so you need to override all methods... I advice to add field to your class `$client` and in constructor just create it:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Vendors\Smsirlaravel;

use Ipecompany\Smsirlaravel\Smsirlaravel;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class SendSmsIr extends Smsirlaravel {
  protected $client;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->client = new Client(['verify' => config('smsirlaravel.ssl_verify')]);
  }

  /** other methods */
}
```

in `config/smsirlaravel.php` just add this line to array

`'ssl_verify' => false, // true, false or path to certificate '/path/to/cert.pem'`

Comment: can you please tell me where can i find this setting ??

Comment: Or set 'verify' => false directly in Client request