# cURL error 60: SSL certificate: unable to get local issuer certificate - DigiCert

Tags: php, ssl, ssl-certificate, guzzle

I have a production and a test server. Then I have a 3rd party program with a test and a production environment.

Tests are bond together and productions are bond together.

3rd party production server has a `DigiCert Global Root G2` and the test server has a `DigiCert Global Root CA`.

My servers share the environment configuration and **both certificates are** in `/etc/ssl/certs`.

I call it with **GuzzleHttp**.

```
$client = new Client([
    'base_uri' => 'www.example.com',
]);

$data = [
    'json' => $jsonData
    'expect' => false,
    'auth' => [username, password, basic]
];

$client->request('POST', 'api/endpoint1', $data);
```

The production server works fine but the test server throws error `cURL error 60: SSL certificate: unable to get local issuer certificate`.

There is a certificate chain (not sure how this works):

```
0 s:/CN=www.example.com
i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=RapidSSL RSA CA 2018
1 s:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=RapidSSL TLS RSA CA G1
i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert Global Root G2
```

1. I need to find out whose fault is that - mine or 3rd party?
2. How can it be fixed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cURL error 60: SSL certificate: unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822686/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that 3rd party has a problem with the certificate. After fix everything works fine now.
So no need to update certificates that were already correct (that was already written in the question).