# Wordpress cURL error 60 wordpress. How to fix it?

Tags: wordpress, ssl, curl

I use wordpress on VDS server with CyberPanel. And i use SSL certificate from Let's Encrypt. If install Health Check & Troubleshooting plugin, it show error:

`cURL error 60: Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized.` and 1 of my plugin doesn't work.

How i can fix this error? Try to use CloudFlare SSL, it's don't help.

Comment: Did you try this solution?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822686/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate

Comment: Glad it fixed     .