# cURL 60 error when trying to access my website's XML file

Tags: ssl, curl, openssl, ssl-certificate, centos6

When I use "curl -v https://hostname/resource.xml" I get the following error:

```
About to connect() to hostname.com port 443 (#0)
Trying x.x.x.x... connected
Connected to hostname.com (x.x.x.x) port 443 (#0)
Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
 CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
CApath: none
Peer's certificate issuer is not recognized: 'CN=InCommon RSA Server CA,OU=InCommon,O=Internet2,L=Ann Arbor,ST=MI,C=US'
NSS error -8179
Closing connection #0
Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates
curl: (60) Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
```

However, when I try: "curl -v https://google.com/"
everything works just fine!

The certificates that validate the websites are located in /etc/ssl/certs

I can assume that this is an issue with SSL certificates and validation because when I run the curl command with -k it works!

I have tried the following to troubleshoot:

> 1. Confirmed that date/time is correct on the server
> 2. updated the cacert.pem certificate (source: [cURL error 60: SSL certificate: unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822686/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate))
> 3. Confirmed that Apache configuration is correct
> 4. Tried adding the SSL certificate (website.crt) to /etc/pki/tls

I am running:

- CentOS release 6.10 (Final)
- curl 7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.27.1 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
- PHP 7.1.32 (cli)

Would this be caused due to SSLCertificateChain being incomplete?

Any help here is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the issuer of your website certificate is an intermediate certificate 
`CN=InCommon RSA Server CA,OU=InCommon,O=Internet2,L=Ann Arbor,ST=MI,C=US`
 but it is not sending the full chain, i.e. it is only sending the website certificate without this intermediate certificate.  You have 2 options:

1. Updated the website configuration to bundle the intermediate certificate with the website certificate (**preferred method**). 
   Follow the instructions [here](https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO15690.html) to update the Apache configuration to use the intermediate certificate.
   Basically you have to modify the httpd.conf file of your Apache installation, specifically the Virtual Host settings for your website, and point the *SSLCertificateChainFile* setting to the PEM  (crt) file that contains the intermediate cert (CN=InCommon RSA Server CA,OU=InCommon,O=Internet2,L=Ann Arbor,ST=MI,C=US)
   You can find the intermediate certificate you are missing on the web, for example [here](https://wiki.cac.washington.edu/display/infra/InCommon+SSL+Intermediate+Certificates), and save this content to a file (e.g. incommon_rsa.crt).  Here is what you need to save in the file:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

2. Add the intermediate certificate to the list of system-trusted CA certificates (**less-preferred method**, intermediate certificates should be sent by clients and not trusted implicitly by adding it to the list of system-trusted CA certs ).
   Again, save the intermediate certificate file with the content I provide above and then install it in your list of trusted CA certificates using the CentOS tools for doing this as described [here](https://techjourney.net/update-add-ca-certificates-bundle-in-redhat-centos/).

Comment: Thank you for responding! I was able to resolve this issue by using the intermediate certificate to complete the chain.

Comment: @J.VWilde Glad to hear you resolved it. Please don't forget to mark this as the accepted answer.