# cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Tags: php, laravel

GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException
cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

how to solve this error i am trying everything available on the google including
the below description several times

---

Download this file: http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
Place this file in the C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.1.9 folder
Open php.iniand find this line:
;curl.cainfo

Change it to:

curl.cainfo = "C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.1.9\cacert.pem"

---

But still it didn't work for me
please help me i am so frustrated right now...

Answer (score 12):

You need to put `.pem` file inside of `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.1.9\extras\ssl` instead of `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.1.9`

Make sure the file `mod_ssl.so` is inside of `C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache(version)\modules`

Enable `mod_ssl` in `httpd.conf` inside of Apache directory `C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.27\conf`

Enable `php_openssl.dll` in `php.ini`.

In wamp there are two php.ini files and You need to do this in both of them.

First one can be located inside of your WAMP taskbar icon

[image]

and the other one is located in `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php(Version)`

find the location for both of the `php.ini` files and find the line `curl.cainfo =` and give it a path like this

`curl.cainfo = "C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.1.9\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"`

Now save the files and restart your server

Comment: I am doing the same and all other API calls on the HTTPS server works fine except one link of the client's server links not work but all other works fine. if I am accessing with HTTP it will work fine kindly help me if you have any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error also happened when using Laravel's development server.

In order to fix it, just shifted stopped that server and ran Apache through XAMPP and that was enough to solve the problem.

If you're having troubles with this approach, please read the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29822686/5675325) for more details.