# Wamp and laravel cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, curl

I'm getting laravel with this error,

> cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer
> certificate (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
> for https://sandbox-api.tilled.com/v1/payment-methods

I'm using PHP 8.1.9, laravel 8.1.2, guzzlehttp/guzzle ^7.0.1 and WAMP for my windows local.

I have set,

curl.cainfo="C:/wamp64/bin/php/cacert.pem" 
openssl.cafile="C:/wamp64/bin/php/cacert.pem" 
openssl.capath="C:/wamp64/bin/php/cacert.pem"

And I download cacert.pem from [here](https://curl.se/ca/cacert.pem) to C:/wamp64/bin/php location.

And I checked [cURL error 60: SSL certificate: unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822686/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top)

But I'm still getting error.

Comment: You can try to disable the SSH verification like this `$client = new Client(['verify' => false]);` - DOC: https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#verify

Comment: Not sure where to do it in laravel. but will try thanks :)

Comment: You can do when you are instantiating the client object `$client = new Client(['verify' => false]);` or when you are making the request, for example `$client->request('GET', '/', ['verify' => false]);`. If you post your code I can help you more.