# I'm getting cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem while everything is okay

Tags: laravel, api, curl, stripe-payments, backend

I'm trying to send a post request in the below code using postman when I got the below this error noting that I added the path of cacert.pem which inside my php version inside the wamp folder to php.ini and uncommented all necessary parts and restarted everything .

`

```
{
    "code": 0,
    "message": "cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens?card%5Bnumber%5D=4242+4242+4242+4242&card%5Bexp_month%5D=02&card%5Bexp_year%5D=2024&card%5Bcvc%5D=123",
    "data": null
}
```

`

My Code where I'm using the post request :

`

```
if ($request->is_male){
                $stripe = Stripe::make(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));
                $token = $stripe->tokens()->create([
                    'card' => [
                        'number' => $request->credit_number,
                        'exp_month' => $request->credit_exp_month,
                        'exp_year' => $request->credit_exp_year,
                        'cvc' => $request->credit_code
                    ],
                ]);


                $customer = $stripe->customers()->create([
                    'email' => $request->email,
                ]);
                $card = $stripe->cards()->create($customer['id'], $token['id']);
                if (!isset($customer['id'])) {
                    return ResponseController::error(-150,"invalid customer");
                }
                $charge = $stripe->charges()->create([
                    'customer'=>$customer['id'],
                    'currency' => 'USD',
                    'amount' => env("pay_amount"),
                    'description' => 'Gyanomi Subscription',
                ]);
                if($charge['status'] != 'succeeded') {

                    throw new \Exception($charge);
                }
            }
```

`

Comment: This has been previously answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822686/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate).

Comment: @Tarzan I followed this instruction before as i'm saying in my question and the problem still exists