# Bypassing SSL Verification | PHP | Error 401

Tags: php, ssl, curl, sendgrid

I'm currently testing a PHP form on the wamp64 local server, obviously this will not be used for full deployment but just to test the functionality of the PHP form.

**I have PHP 7.4.33, Windows 10, & WAMP 3.3.0**

The solutions I have tried (how much time do you have?)

- downloaded the latest `cacert` from [cacert.pem](https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html), uploaded to the `php7.4.33\extras\ssl\` directory & altered the `curl.cainfo = "C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.4.33\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"` in my `php.ini` file - No dice.
- followed the tutorial here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822686/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate](https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html) - didn't even have the options in the relevant files (apart from the `php.ini` file) which the OP has suggested as obviously the config files have been updated since the OP posted the post, so no dice.
- I have used the following code below, note the SSL verify set to false - guess what? Yep, you guessed it - no dice!

How do I bypass the SSL verification because this is getting really silly now?

```
<?php

require_once 'config.php'; //this has been uploaded and in the correct directory
require 'vendor/autoload.php'; //this has been uploaded and in the correct directory

$url    = "https://expired.badssl.com";

$curl   =   curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($resp);

$email =new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail(); 
$email->setFrom("<name>@<domain>.com", "<name>");
$email->setSubject("Sending with SendGrid is a bloody disaster");
$email->addTo("<name>@<domain>.com","<name>");
$email->addTo("<name>@<domain>.com","<name>");
$email->addContent("text/plain", "and is impossible to do anywhere, even with PHP");
$email->addContent("text/plain","This is very much getting ridiculous now");
$email->addContent("text/plain", "Seriously, getting through the Volkswagen customer services is easier than getting to the bottom of this cURL error 60 issue.");
$email->addContent("text/html", "and impossible to do anywhere, even with PHP");

$sendgrid = new \SendGrid(getenv('SENDGRID_API_KEY')); //variable in 'config.json' file

try {
    $response = $sendgrid->send( $email );
    print $response->statusCode() . "\n";
    print_r( $response->headers() );
    print $response->body() . "\n";
    
} catch ( Exception $e ) {

    echo 'Caught exception: '. $e->getMessage() ."\n"; 

}
```

Comment: Your code contains two sections - a curl request and a sendgrid email - which of the two is failing? 401 in SendGrid (and in internet land) means Unauthorized, are you sure that `getenv('SENDGRID_API_KEY')` returns the correct API key?

Comment: what error are you getting exactly? are you hitting the ```} catch ( Exception $e ) {echo 'Caught exception: '. $e->getMessage() ."\n"; ``` code? what is the message? and what you get from `var_dump($e);` ? - voted to close this question as "needs debugging details".

Comment: Why are you trying to bypass SSL verification?

Comment: I'm not trying to bypass anything, I'm just trying to get something to actually work on this thing - which would be a miracle conserving whoever wrote the API documentation doesn't have a clue as to what they're doing - as I have proven to SendGrid.