# Guzzle requestAsync to the self/same server gives SSL certificate error

Tags: ssl, guzzle, php-curl

I am trying to make an `async` guzzle call to 2 other APIs running on the same server. This way I just want to combine the 2 API calls running concurrently.

```php
$params = []
$client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'https://test.local', 'cookies' => true]);

$promises = [
            'first' => $client->requestAsync($method, '/api/first', ['form_params' => $params]),
            'second' => $client->requestAsync($method, '/api/second', ['form_params' => $params]),
];

$responses = Utils::unwrap($promises);
```

But everytime I run this throws SSL certificate error
Error: `cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: self-signed certificate`
This must be because of the same domains Client/Server.

Tried with tricking different domain name then working.

> Note: The `certificate.pem` is installed and integrated in `php.ini`
> file. the SSL all working for other straight-forward calls. just not
> working for this particular case.
> `curl.cainfo = "C:\laragon\etc\ssl\cacert.pem"` in php.ini

Comment: Does the answer here help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822686/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate You either need to to get an officially signed cert, or you need to install the generator of the cert as a trusted root authority, or you need to find a Guzzle / cURL / PHP switch or config that accepts self signed certificates, or you need to use HTTP instead of HTTPS

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I forgot to mention. the certificate is already integrated. I updated my post with same note.

Comment: So if you hit that URL directly (from the PHP server) using a browser you don't get any SSL error?

Comment: the first,second api call if i hit directly from the postman. working fine. yeh..