SSL Issues with windows 11 and laravel trying to install vapor to deploy an app
I am stuck with trying to get the SSL certificates working, I have done all the cacert downloads and updated my php.ini file yet when I try to run simple commands from the cli to install the vapor cli globally or even per app I can't seem to get past the SSL problems.
composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
https://repo.packagist.org could not be fully loaded (curl error 60 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate), package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date                                                                                                                                    

In CurlDownloader.php line 370:
                                                                                                                                                     
  curl error 60 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/p2/laravel/vapor.json: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate 

Thanks in advance!
Every thing, expecting to install vapor, i can't even run composer update without getting the same SSL certificate problems

Have you tried googling it? I come down to this SO question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822686/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate

Hey mate, yeah done many hours of googling and trying everything under the sun to get it to work. I ended up just giving up untill I get some one with many years of experience and on a windows OS to help me out. Quiet sad but i've just moved onto React only for now
