cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate WITHOUT ANY UPDATES made by me (three days everything was working fine)
Since this morning I receive for any Get or Post call (in Local) to all external APIs the error:

"cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"

I specify that until 3 days ago everything was working fine, and both PHP and cacert.pem are correctly configured.
I checked these posts in the URLs below, but everything is already configured correctly.
As already mentioned, until a few days ago everything was working correctly.
Post 1
Post 2
The only way to make it work was to insert a global option with verify =》false for http calls.
I get this error for any api call I try to make, even without the need to add a token.
For example, I get this error for the api on this site.
Has anyone had or is having the same problem?
I also tried to change the project thinking it was a project problem, but I find this error in other projects too.

Did you try checking you had the latest version of the .pem file?

Yes, but not working

Perhaps try the solution listed here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822686/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate . I know it's old, but it's likely the local certificate is expired.

If you're on linux there's likely a package like ca-certificates that you just need to update to update your root certs.
