# Laravel dumpautoload url malformed

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to run

```
composer dump-autoload
```

During this process I get this error

```
> @php artisan package:discover

In Util.php line 45:

  Curl error (code 3): <url> malformed
```

Here are my depencies

```
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "ext-json": "*",
    "abdelrahmanbadr/pipl-laravel": "dev-master",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "forxer/gravatar": "^2.1",
    "giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php": "^8.10",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
    "htmlmin/htmlmin": "^5.7",
    "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
    "roykesserwani/piplapis-php7.2": "^1.0",
    "sentry/sentry-laravel": "^0.11.0",
    "stripe/stripe-php": "^6.28",
    "symfony/psr-http-message-bridge": "^1.1"
```

Here the log from `composer update`

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating optimized autoload files
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "JsonSerializable" was found in both "/var/www/lycus.ch/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/JsonSerializable.php" and "/var/www/lycus.ch/vendor/roykesserwani/piplapis-php7.2/src/piplapis/data/utils.php", the first will be used.
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "JsonSerializable" was found in both "/var/www/lycus.ch/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/JsonSerializable.php" and "/var/www/lycus.ch/vendor/roykesserwani/piplapis-php7.2/src/piplapis/data/utils.php", the first will be used.
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover

In Util.php line 45:

  Curl error (code 3): <url> malformed
```

What is wrong with my laravel application?

Comment: Can you try a `composer update` to see if you have any other errors?

Comment: I've added the output

Comment: From what I've found so far that error is from `guzzlehttp/guzzle`. How are you using it? Can you show some code that uses that? EX: `$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();`

Comment: Dont using it in my project. It's only used by the Laravel Framework

Comment: Do you instantiate a `client ` somewhere in the project? EX: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722822/guzzle-returns-curl-error-3-url-malformed